# Add a "Share/Send To" capability to an Android app

Tags: java, android, video

I am developing an Android app that has the feature of converting a video to an audio file.

I want to add a feature that makes the user able to enter his studio, then when they click on the `video-share` option (to share the video), to find my application icon at the bottom. Without the need to open the application.

How can I do that?

Comment: I haven't used Java in a long time but maybe [this share/receive guide](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive) will help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is  this  [share/receive guide](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive)

thanks  VC.One that is exactly what i need

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).